# On Köthe sequence spaces

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Hans Jarchow in his ["Locally convex spaces"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-322-90559-8) defines the Köthe sequence space $\Lambda(P)$ by the condition 
$$
\lambda\in\Lambda(P)\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad \forall \alpha\in P\quad \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n\cdot|\lambda_n|<\infty,
$$
where $P$ is an arbitrary set of sequences with the properties:

1) $\forall\alpha\in P$ $\forall n\in{\mathbb N}$ $\alpha_n\ge 0$,

2) $\forall\alpha,\beta\in P$ $\exists\gamma\in P$ $\forall n\in{\mathbb N}$ $\max\{\alpha_n,\beta_n\}\le\gamma_n$

3) $\forall n\in{\mathbb N}$ $\exists\alpha\in P$ $\alpha_n>0$.

Jarchow mentions the space $\Lambda(P)$ from time to time in his book to illustrate (sometimes to formulate) different results, but without a summary about $\Lambda(P)$.

I wonder if there is a text where the results on $\Lambda(P)$ are systematized? I think the main properties of $\Lambda(P)$ as a topological vector space, like barreledeness, nuclearity, reflexivity, Heine-Borel property, completeness in different senses, etc. can be stated on one page. Can anybody enlighten me if such a text exists?

P.S. Actually, the other properties of $\Lambda(P)$, where it is not considered as a topological vector space are interesting as well... Is it true, for example, that if a sequence $\{\omega_n\}$ has the property 
$$
\forall\lambda\in \Lambda(P)\quad \text{the series}\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \omega_n\cdot\lambda_n \ \text{converges}
$$
then there are $\alpha\in P$ and $C>0$ such that
$$
\forall n\in{\mathbb N}\quad |\omega_n|\le C\cdot\alpha_n
$$
?

**Edit 22.05.2020.** I asked this also at [MathOveflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/361048/on-k%C3%B6the-sequence-spaces).